# SELECT account_id and get name from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display a list of times with this query:

```
SELECT `account_id`, `finish_time` FROM `race_times` WHERE `race_id` = %i ORDER BY `finish_time` ASC LIMIT 10
```

It will return field 'account_id'
, but 'account_name' can be changed by the user and is stored in table **'Users'** which also has the original account_id value from auto increment.

Is it possible to make the query above to return 'account_name' from table **'Users'** when table **'race_times'** only has the 'account_id' value in it?

Comment: It's called a "join". Google should help you get the rest. (SO: Is there a canonical answer for this question?)

Comment: how about some data?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rt.account_id, rt.finish_time, u.account_name
FROM race_times AS rt
INNER JOIN users AS u ON tr.account_id = u.account_id
WHERE race_id = %i
ORDER BY finish_time ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `account_id`, `finish_time`,account_name FROM `race_times`,users  WHERE `race_id` = %i and users.account_id=race_times.account_id ORDER BY `finish_time` ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It should work. wonder why the answer is voted not useful though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use inner join or simply use both the tables in your query

Select u.account_name,rt.account_id, rt.finish_time from race_time as rt, users as u where u.account_id = rt.account_id and rt.race_id=%i